# Drag & drop the class files from one package to another is not happening in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

**I am using the Android studio version:**

```
Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.12.6
```

- In earlier versions of android studio, I was able to drag & drop the
  class files from one package to another and refractor would happen
  automatically.
- Its not happening, Now class files appears to have locked.
- How to resolve this

Comment: Sometimes this happend with android studio so Select File:-> invalid cache/restart android studio..

Comment: @ChiragNahar  Please post this as answer, it actually worked .... LOLzz .. I taught its a feature of android studio :D

Answer (score 0):

try to copy paste the folder or class rather than using drag and drop. I hope it will work for you.